# scheme function checking constants/vowels

Tags: scheme, racket

How to create a function in Dr. Racket consumes a string **str** and produces true if **str** has at least a vowel and false if **str** has no vowels.

The vowels are the following set of characters: A, a, E, e, I, i, O, o, U, u.

For example:

```
         (has-vowel? "whatever") => true 
         (has-vowel? "trythnks") => false
```

---

@ÓscarLópez 
This is what I have come up with so far. THe function can whether the first letter is a vowel or not. My problem now is, how do I get the function to check the other letters?

I keep getting this error in Scheme  *(rest: expects a non-empty list; given "string")*

I'm don't know exactly how to fix it. Any help/suggestions is most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: @Oscar thank you sooo much for helping me. I owe you more than you could ever imagine. thanks !

Comment: the error you're getting means that you're passing a string and not a list to `rest`. Remember that `any-list` receives a _list_ so `has-vowel?` must convert the string to a list befor passing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework, so I'll give you some hints to get started. First, let's split the problem in two procedures - the first one will transform the string into a list of characters, and will also define the list of characters we're looking for. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (has-vowel? str)
  (any-in-list        ; helper procedure, we'll get to this later
   (<???> str)        ; how to transform a string into a list of chars?
   '(#\A #\a <???>))) ; list of vowels
```

With the above procedure in place, we can write our helper procedure, `any-in-list`. It's a general solution for determining if any of the elements in one list is in the other - think about it as a predicate that tells if the intersection of two lists is non-empty:

```
(define (any-in-list lst check)
  (cond (<???> <???>) ; if lst is empty, we didn't find any element, return #f
        (<???> #t)    ; return #t if the first element in lst is in check
        (else (any-in-list <???> check)))) ; else advance the recursion over lst
```

The tricky part is in the second line of `any-in-list`. How do we determine if an element is in another list? we could write another helper procedure for this, but a quick look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._member%29%29) will get you right on track. And don't forget to test your code, this should work as expected:

```
(has-vowel? "whatever")
=> #t
(has-vowel? "trythnks")
=> #f
```

Comment: thanks so much for all your help! I really appreciate it. reached another speed bump though in my recursion/coding. will reply properly in a newer edit above. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to:

1. convert the string to a list of characters ([string->list](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3elist%29%29))
2. Iterate over the list and check for vowel characters ([characters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/characters.html))